# Linked List overload operator = Run time error

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, linked-list

So I am really frustrated as to why this is happening. I am implementing a class that is similar to std::string but this is using Link List instead of arrays. my overloaded operator = is not working for some odd reason. below you can see, when I print the pointer inside the method the string is copied to the link list, however when I create a string object with this pointer to return, then the console prints out infinite junk. any ideas to what I am missing here ?  (I am only pasting related code)

```
static int NumAllocations = 0;

struct ListNode {
    char info;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode () : info('0'), next(0) {}
    ListNode ( char c ) : info (c), next(0) {}


};


class MyString {
 private:
    ListNode *head;
    static void delstring (ListNode *l);
    static int strlen (ListNode * head);
    static ListNode* strcpy (ListNode *dest, ListNode *src);
 public:

MyString::MyString () : head(0) {}

MyString::MyString (ListNode *l) : head(l) {}

MyString::MyString( const MyString & s ) {
    if (s.head == 0)
        head = 0;
    else
        head = strcpy(head, s.head);
}


MyString MyString::operator = (const MyString & s ){               
    ListNode *renew = NULL;
    if (head != s.head) {
        if (head != 0)
            delstring(this -> head);

        head = strcpy(head, s.head);
        // printList(head); (this prints out the string just fine, so it must be the                                   constructor ? but what about it ?!

        MyString res (head);
        return res;
    }
}


MyString::~MyString(){
    if (head == 0)
        return;
    ListNode *temp = NULL;
    do {
        temp = head -> next;
        delete head;
        -- NumAllocations;
        head = temp;
    } while (temp != 0);
}
```

STATIC PUBLIC FUNCTIONS

```
ListNode* MyString::strcpy (ListNode *dest, ListNode *src){
    dest = new ListNode (src -> info);
    ++ NumAllocations;
    ListNode *iter = dest;
    for (ListNode *ptr = src -> next; ptr != 0; ptr = ptr ->next){
        iter -> next = new ListNode (ptr -> info);
        iter = iter -> next;
        ++ NumAllocations;
    }
    return dest;
}


void MyString::delstring (ListNode *l){
    if (l == 0)
        return;
    ListNode *temp = NULL;
    do {
        temp = l -> next;
        delete []l;

        -- NumAllocations;
        l = temp;
    } while (temp != 0);
    l = 0;
}
```

Comment: Class definitions would assist this effort nicely. The node-management code even more-so. And I see zero-reason why `dest` is even *supplied* to the poorly named `strcpy` member. It is passed by value, and whatever it was is *immediately* lost on the first line, so it may as well be a local variable and not a parameter at all. That function looks like it may be a problem, so I'd start there.

Comment: I added the class definitions. strcpy is a member function of std::string and this class is to be as identical as possible to that, hence the name picking.  like I mentioned the list is copied properly, because when i print it right before returning, it prints fine, it messes up when i try to create a new object with that pointer "head" in the last 2 lines of operator = method.

Answer (score 2):

Two things are fundamentally wrong with your assignment operator.

- Not all control paths return values.
- You shouldn't need the temp-final copy in the first place. The function should be returning a *reference*, specifically `*this`.

So...

```
MyString& MyString::operator = (const MyString & s )
{               
    if (head != s.head) 
    {
        if (head != 0)
            delstring(this -> head);
        head = strcpy(head, s.head);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Also, everything I see in this code says the `ListNode` objects are allocated individually and linked together, yet in the `delstring` member you do this:

```
void MyString::delstring (ListNode *l)
{
    if (l == 0)
        return;
    ListNode *temp = NULL;
    do {
        temp = l -> next;
        delete []l;  // <<==== vector delete of single allocated item

        -- NumAllocations;
        l = temp;
    } while (temp != 0);
    l = 0;
}
```

Maybe try this instead:

```
void MyString::delstring (ListNode *& l)
{
    while (l)
    {
        ListNode *temp = l;
        l = l->next;
        delete temp;
        --NumAllocations;
    }
}
```

note this takes a pointer-reference rather than a pointer. it will set the caller's pointer to nullptr once the list is empty (assuming you properly terminated your list on construction, and it looks like you do).

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help, I am sorry that I didn't include more of the code, didn't want to over complicated the issue but I guess I made it worse. I do have a copy constructor written, it is now included as well as the destructor. I can clearly see your point on return this. I will try and see if that changes anything. (but I suspect that the destructor is doing something wrong, since printing the object inside this method (print (objhead)) prints the string, but in main, its a different story.

Comment: @WhosCraig  you are awesome man, that function above works perfect. I still don't understand why building a new object was messing it up, but it was obviously wrong. thanks a lot for putting through reading all that messy code!

Comment: @Tangleman there is still another issue, and it is likely related; improper vector destruction of the node allocations. I'll throw it in then leave it to you.

Comment: @WhosCraig haha alright if you just point it out and ill try to figure it out, but so far everything works, i still have more methods to do such as overload +=, +, >>, and things like find etc.

Comment: @WhosCraig    Oh okay, I accidentally put "[]" before head, it meant to be delete head, just like the destructor, I will fix that also. again thanks for the help! hopefully the rest will be cake.

Comment: Your destructor should be one line: `delstring(head);`

Comment: yup I will do that too, I gotta clean some stuff up.